# logback-access %b output is weird

Tags: tomcat, logback, access-log

I use logback-access instead of tomcat default valve.

I used %b pattern, but output is so weird.

First, i use class "ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve"

I wrote this pattern.

```html
[%t]\t%U\t%s\t%D\t%b
```

Second, i use class "org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"

I wrote this pattern.

```html
pattern="%t&#9;%U&#9;%s&#9;%D&#9;%b
```

I think they are same, and try use same time.
But "%b" attribute output is different.

This is example.

First, Logback.

[02/Jun/2015:20:12:28 +0900]    /test/testLayout.css    200 366 -

Second, Tomcat valve.

[02/Jun/2015:20:12:28 +0900]    /test/testLayout.css    200 367 2769

Logback's output is "-" but Tomcat is "2769"

I think Tomcat valve's value is correct.

Why they are different?

Please tell your advice.

ps. Logback version is 1.1.3. I use logback-core-1.1.3.jar, logback-classic-1.1.3.jar. When use logback-access-1.1.3 at the same time, tomcat puts error.